# Will I lose water pressure going from a 2" pipe to a 1/2" pipe then back to 2"?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, pool

I have jimmied up a pool heater from an idea on YouTube, but just expanded it.  I have a water line of 2" PVC, piped down to 1/2" copper, so it can run through a coil, then increased back to 2" PVC, and re-connected with the original pool hose of 2".

Will this keep the constant pressure that it starts with, or will I lose water pressure. It seems to have lost pressure, trying to get back into the 2" inch hose. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Going from a 2" pipe to a 1/2" pipe you're loosing almost 95% of your cross section. There's definitely going to be flow restriction. Not to mention the increased length from running the water through a heat exchanger coil or whatever you have set up.

Comment: By the way, do not confuse pressure with flow rate or velocity. You say that the water appears to be "losing pressure" as it comes out of the 1/2" pipe, but in reality that expansion doesn't really cause any restriction. Much of the flow loss occurs where the water enters the 1/2" section, and then the long length of small pipe causes additional flow losses.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the pressure loss depends on the flow rate. There will be some loss of pressure.

To avoid it you need 2" copper pipe or multiple parallel 1/2" pipes (probably more than 16).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have a feeling your design looks like this:

[image]

You should do this instead:

[image]

If you make 16 parallel copper circuits, that would have an equivalent cross-section or a 2 inch pipe. However, I would probably do more like 20 circuits because all of those bends are going to introduce additional pumping/pressure losses and the extra circuits will make up for those losses.

Comment: I tried to post a pic there of what i have...do you think if I just run a 1/2 inch hose from the end of the copper to the pool, that would solve the problem? (eliminate the back to 2 inch conversion?)

Comment: No. The problem isn't that you are restricted after the copper, but that the copper itself is the restriction.

Comment: Actually, a sudden enlargement in the pipe *does* cause some restriction, counterintuitively. But by far most of the restriction is going to come from the 2" -> 1/2" change and the long length of 1/2" pipe.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't add parallel paths through the heater as @redgrittybrick suggests, add a bypass with 2" pipe and a throttling valve.  The valve will let you balance overall flow vs heat gain.

[image]

The bypass arrangement will lessen the strain on your pump seals and motor.